# Embedding modified sub-frame into the original one

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have 2 pandas data frames which one of them consists the modified selected rows of the first one (they have similar columns).
For simplicity the below frames illustrate this problem.

```
df1 =                 df2 =
      A B C                  A B C
0     1 2 3           1      20 30 40
1     2 3 4           3      40 50 60
2     3 4 5
3     4 5 6
```

Is there any more efficient and pythonic way than the below code,to embedding the df2 into df1 by overwriting values? (working with high-dimensional frames)

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1.ix[index,:] = df2.ix[index, :]
```

which results in:

```
df1 =
     A  B  C
0    1  2  3
1    20 30 40
2    3  4  5
3    40 50 60
```

Comment: `df1.update(df2)` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update a df with another df, where the row and column labels agree the values are updated, you will need to cast to `int` using `astype` because the dtype is changed to float due to missing values:

```
In [21]:
df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.astype(int)
df1

Out[21]:
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1  20  30  40
2   3   4   5
3  40  50  60
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I checked it and it was exactly what i needed.